# ApiController and Controll inherit from same base class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have multiple controllers and apicontrollers in my project.

How to make both types of controllers inherit a base class, as there is more than some methods, that I need in both?

Answer (score 3):

Composition might be a better option.

Basically instead of inheriting to gain the functionality stick it in a common class, that can be included as a property in both the Api and standard controller.

You can then inject the dependancy into both.

For example:

```
public class CommonControllerLogic : ICommonControllerLogic 
{
  public ActionResult SomeSortOfMethod() 
  {
     // etc..
  }
}

public class MobileApiController: ApiController 
{
  public ICommonControllerLogic CommonControllerLogic  {get;set;}

  // etc..
}

public class HomeController: Controller 
{
  public ICommonControllerLogic CommonControllerLogic  {get;set;}

  // etc..
}
```

Composition is often [favoured over inheritence,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) there are loads of articles on it, just do a quick google search, have a read of [this article](http://www.hautelooktech.com/2013/02/05/design-principle-favor-composition-over-inheritance/).

Comment: I hoped - there would be another solution, but this could help. So I just make another class for ApiController and they both has the same type of single property.

Comment: @SpoksSt see edits above, note composition is generally favoured over inheritence.

Comment: problem is that I need controllers properties fos those methods such as current user. And I do not know now that I will need more from controller.

Answer (score 0):

MVC controllers inherit from `Controller`, whereas API controllers inherit from `ApiController`.  C# does not support multiple inheritance easily. I would recommend moving the shared logic into a static class that both can call. Otherwise you could provide more detail about what is shared; in some cases other design patterns may be more appropriate.

Comment: In my case static class is not an option, as data in parent is per instance.

Comment: You can still pass the instance data to the static class's method. In general it's a lot easier to help if you post some code.

Comment: Base class is accessing DB (EF) and other user specific data.